# Como fazer diversas divs que alternam entre visível e invisível?

Tags: html, angularjs

Sou iniciante em AngularJS, e não sei como proceder neste caso.

Sei criar um painel que pode aparecer e desaparecer conforme uma variável no controller, tipo isso:

```html
<div class="toggle-box">
  <div ng-click="visivel = !visivel">
    Clica!
  </div>
  <div ng-show="visivel">
    Eu só vou aparecer quando visivel === true
  </div>
</div>
```

Só que eu não sei fazer isso quando existe apenas um painel. Mas e se houver multiplos?

Por exemplo, como eu poderia fazer todos os `div.toggle-box` terem essa função de alternar a visibilidade?

```html
<div class="toggle-box">
  <div ng-click="visivel = !visivel">
    Primeiro painel
  </div>
  <div ng-show="visivel">
    Eu só vou aparecer quando visivel === true
  </div>
</div>

<div class="toggle-box">
  <div ng-click="visivel = !visivel">
    Segundo painel
  </div>
  <div ng-show="visivel">
    Eu só vou aparecer quando visivel === true
  </div>
</div>

...

<div class="toggle-box">
  <div ng-click="visivel = !visivel">
    Enésimo painel
  </div>
  <div ng-show="visivel">
    Eu só vou aparecer quando visivel === true
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução para o problema.

Terei que criar um controller único para esse tipo de div, e para cada `div.toggle-box` que eu criar, terei que inserir o atributo `ng-controller` apontando para o controlador criado.

Eu imaginei que fazendo isso, todas as `div.toggle-box` que eu criasse usaria o mesmo controlador (mesmo objeto), mas o angular instancia um controlador único para cada vez que ele é chamado.

Parece que ainda tenho bastante para aprender em relação à como funciona o angular...

Answer (score 0):

basta voce puxar para cima o ng-show conforme abaixo:

```
<div class="toggle-box" ng-show="visivel">
  <div ng-click="visivel = !visivel">
    Enésimo painel
  </div>
  <div>
    Eu só vou aparecer quando visivel === true
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nesse caso, a `div.toggle-box` sumiria depois de clicar no painel, sendo impossível fazer ele voltar a ser visível novamente. E outra, como existem diversas `div.toggle-box`, assim que você clicar na primeira, as restantes também sumiriam, já que o `visivel` se tornaria `false`...

Comment: Voce poderia colocar uma outra div, ou um botao para fazer isso.